# Do black holes release space through Hawking Radiation?

Tags: gravity, black-holes, spacetime, hawking-radiation

It is my understanding that black holes lose mass through Hawking Radiation, and because gravity is a function of mass the black hole has a lesser gravitational pull as it loses mass. Further, gravity compresses space, so doesn't it follow that as a black hole loses mass through Hawking Radiation it also releases compressed space?

Comment: Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/26605/what-is-hawking-radiation-and-how-does-it-cause-a-black-hole-to-evaporate?rq=1.  I think by compressed space you mean an extremely curved space and I can sort of see what you are getting at, if you assume the mass diminishes resulting in a flatter "normal" space, but space being compressed is not terminology in common usage, if I follow you properly.