# Can black holes really evaporate?

Tags: black-holes, universe, hawking-radiation

Stephen hawkings black hole evaporation theory assumes evaporation of black holes by losing mass through virtual particle radiation. As far as i know, the theory isn't based on mathematical foundations, assumes evaporation to take uncomprehensible number of years, no comment on the information lost to black hole and no comment on what happens inside. Despite all these, why people treat it like a Law of nature? Why black holes canNOT evaporate? Any counter argument/comment against stephen hawkings theory is especially welcome.

Comment: Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/26605/2451 and links therein.

Comment: Welcome *New contributor* A. A.! I've downvoted your question for the "it is unclear" reason.  Much of your post seems to me to be on the 'rant' spectrum. It isn't clear what you're looking for with "Why black holes canNOT evaporate?"

Comment: Alfred Centauri i believe the question is quite clear. Maybe you are bored of physics that started to downvote questions

Comment: G.Smith and John Rennie, why did you tag the question as duplicate? I never asked an explanation into the theory. Maybe i should do the same with your questions. Then you'll be happy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hawking radiation is theorized through the mathematical formalism of Quantum Field theory in Curved spacetime.

What is interesting about Hawking radiation is that it's a *kinematic effect* of General Relativity, not a dynamical one. This means that you don't need to have a full theory of a back-reacting quantum field and Einstein's Equations to derive Hawking radiation-a quantum field on a fixed Schwartzchild background is sufficient.

In fact, when you put a quantum (eg. phonon) field on a fluid background (eg. Bose-Einstein Condensate in certain regimes) with an event horizon (i.e. fluid flow faster than speed of sound), you get thermal radiation coming off the event horizon (Reference: [1809.00913](https://arxiv.org/abs/1809.00913)). What this means is that the idea of Hawking radiation isn't unique to Quantum Field theory in Curved spacetime, but also shows up anytime there is an effective metric, as in certain hydrodynamic systems.

Comment: Pabetism thank you for the answer. I don't agree with you but that you have you used so many terms in your answer, it will take some time for me to give you a good answer. Till then.